# Why doesn't Application.DoEvents() allow the WebBrowser Control to process

Tags: c#

I'm using C# with VS2012 to create an application containing a WebBrowser.

After every [x] seconds of inactivity, I want my application to navigate back to its home page (This is designed as a terminal application). In principle, this is no problem, but I've stumbled upon an edge case:

If the user has clicked something that invokes, for example, a JavaScript MessageBox my browser gets stuck in a "Busy" state. The end result being that any attempts to navigate end up with a COM error (0x800700AA).

Using the user32.dll SendMessage function, I'm able to find and close the Window. Now, if my function ends at that point the WebBrowser carries on processing whatever script has invoked the window and eventually stops being busy. Here it is in pseudo code:

```
// This works so long as there isn't a dialog 

private void NavigateHome(){

webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

}

// This works to close the dialog and lets the browser return as not busy

private void NavigateHome(){

CloseWindows(); //Calls user32.dll

}

// This, again, works as long there isn't a dialog, otherwise the COM error returns

private void NavigateHome(){

CloseWindows(); //Calls user32.dll
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

}

// I thought this would be the solution, but the browser never continues processing

private void NavigateHome(){

CloseWindows(); //Calls user32.dll

while(webBrowser.isBusy){

Application.DoEvents();

}

webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

}
```

Now, I guess the "proper" solution would be to watch the DocumentCompleted event after closing the window, BUT this doesn't feel very resilient. Ultimately, I don't really care about the document - I just want to return back to my original page. Has anyone got any ideas how should I proceed with this?

And I'd also like to know why Application.DoEvents() doesn't work like I expected.

Comment: I'm assuming your `webBrowser` is simply stuck in the `while` loop. That's what it `isBusy` doing. It's difficult to say without seeing more of the code. Also, never use `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: @Ginosaji I'm aware of the dangers of DoEvents, but my point is that if the function ends the WebBrowser will go off and sort itself out. But that doesn't happen with DoEvents and I don't understand why.

Comment: What event handler(s) are you expecting to execute that will make it no longer busy?

Comment: @Ginosaji What do you mean, sorry?

Comment: `DoEvents` processes all queued window messages and then returns. Unless there is a message in the queue that is going to set `isBusy` to `false`, calling `DoEvents` won't help you here. It's an outdated method to keep the UI (relatively) responsive while performing a long task on the UI thread.

Comment: @Ginosaji Yeah, so given that the WebBrowser runs on the UI thread I'd have thought that it would process whatever it needs to process?

Comment: As I said, it's difficult to say without seeing more of the code. I have no idea how `isBusy` gets set to false.

Comment: @Ginosaji isBusy is built into the WebBrowser Control and it gets set whenever the browser thinks it's processing something

Comment: How have you explained how Applicatino.DoEvents hasn't worked as expected?  You have a messagebox showing, processing all the events--nothing will "continue" until it gets a message that closes the message box.  How would the user be able to click on anything to get this message box until *after* DocummentCompleted?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: The way I understood it is that `CloseWindows` does actually close the `MessageBox`, but the thread just gets stuck in the `while` loop processing irrelevant window messages because `isBusy` never gets set to `false` (presumably because `NavigateHome` has not returned). But it's all speculation; it's impossible for us to fix based on the limited code we were provided.

Comment: @Ginosaji That's exactly right, I'm struggling to explain (not a programmer by trade). I'm not sure what code to post?

Comment: @Ginosaji NavigateHome is called by a timer every [x] seconds. IsBusy is internal to the web control. If there is no dialogue/message box its false, but stays true while the message box is shown. If I just call CloseWindows and end the method there, the web control does its thing and isBusy goes back to false and I can safely navigate.

Comment: You got ERROR_BUSY back as a return code.  You kinda whacked by hacking the window that but now you are still finding out it is actually busy.  So that didn't actually fix the problem.  You'd better focus on what the heck that Javascript is doing to hang the browser.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Hans, I don't think it's a JavaScript problem. The same issue also happens using this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I moved my "CloseWindow()" function to a Background Worker thread. This thread can then wait while the WebBrowser (on the GUI Thread) continues to process whatever it needs to process to return not busy.